# How to read the Go docs?

Tags: go

I've created a simple go program (basically just example code):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func getPage(url string) (body []byte, err error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    body = nil

    if (err != nil) {
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    return
}

func main() {
    startUrl := "http://slashdot.org/"

    body, err := getPage(startUrl)

    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }

    fmt.Println(body)
}
```

I'm trying to go through the docs to understand how it all fits together.

First issue: http.Get(). It's not in the docs (at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/). Except it is, but under Response. However there are 2 other Get() functions. How do I know that net/http.Get is actually the Get() on the Response type?

Anyway, so http.Get() returns a Response with a `Body` of `io.ReadCloser`. ioutil.ReadAll() takes an io.Reader - but how can I find other functions that accept this as a parameter? It kind of seems like the docs are 'backwards' - if I know which function I want I can find docs, but if I have a type, how can I find what functions will work with it?

Comment: +1 for a 'teach me to fish' rather than a 'gimme a fish' question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions are defined like this :

```
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
func (h Header) Get(key string) string
func Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
```

See [how functions are declared](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations).

Between `func` and the name of the function (`Get`), you have the receiver type and name (between parenthesis). Only one of those functions has no receiver and must be called directly prefixed by the package name (`http`). That's the one you need.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. How about finding which functions accept a certain type (so for example I know the options for reading from a Reader)?

Comment: @user1491250: you'd need an index on all of the Go docs, because `Reader` is used throughout the stdlib.

Comment: If you mean the functions accepting a Reader as parameter, you can't : they may be in other packages so only an index based search (depending on the indexed packages) can give this list. The best I have is [this](http://golang.org/search?q=Reader). Better search functions could be built but they'll always be limited by the need to know in what packages to search (might be the standard packages, though, for many uses).

Comment: So are people just expected to trawl through the docs until they stumble across a function that does what they want? How do people do this in practice? For example I can read a Reader and receive a byte array, but I want to know if anything will return me a string. How could I find out?

Comment: Well. You have a good point here. The best answer I have is that the packages are designed to be small and obvious, so that you don't really search. Better docs search features will probably be available in the future.

Comment: Well that might be my learning project. Use Go to concurrently parse the source code and build an index that would allow you to see which functions accept which parameters.

Comment: @user1491250: re: docs hidden under type: 1) open http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ 2) pres <ctrl>-f 3) write `func g` 4) click the highlighted link 5) read the docs

Comment: @jnml thanks i know how to search in a web page. i was looking for how to find functions that accept particular types as parameters in any package.

Comment: - I was not teaching you hot to search in a web page. My reply starts with 're: docs hidden under type', ok? - To find functions that accept particular types as parameters in any package, which I never needed in my fifth years of Go hacking, I would suggest to use [e]grep.

Comment: to convert a `[]byte` to a `string` use a simple type convertion: var str = string(byteArray)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your `io.Reader` and `io.ReadCloser` question:

Those are interfaces, if you are not familiar with them read up on them [here](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types)

Interfaces are basically sets of methods, these two are defined as follows:

```
type Reader interface{
     Read([]byte)(int, error)
}

type ReadCloser interface{
     Read([]byte)(int, error)
     Close()
}
```

This means any concrete datatype that has a Read Method with the above signature can be passed on as a io.Reader. A datatype that satisfies io.ReadCloser definitely does this, since it has to provide the Read method and an additional close Method.

So you can simply pass your ReadCloser on as Reader.

The way interfaces work in go is a little hard to grasp at the beginning since they are so implicit,
however they are very powerful and give you lot's of possibilities. Definitely read the text I linked above. I read the whole thing down, when I was starting with go and it made things a lot easier.